# Comparing two same string but returning false in C#. Don't know why????

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, c#-3.0

```
     public bool VerifyTextPresent(By by, String actual)
    {
            WaitUntilElementIsPresent(by);
            String expected = GetText(by);
            return expected.Equals(actual);

    }
```

expected = "Total Win"

actual =  "Total Win"

I used "Contains" method also but return false only.
Please help me out on this.

Comment: Hope there are no spaces around your string and you tried `Trim()`

Comment: I tried it with that also but still not working

Comment: Can you point to the variable add capture the values using screenshots? Please add them to your question showing both values instead of typing in the values in question.

Comment: Here in this "by" is XPATH to pick the value and it is picking that "Total Win"

Comment: Are you sure the expected and actual are the same? It should work and return true! Is there maybe a single space in one and double space in the other (between Total and Win). Are your cases mixed? I.e. try expected.Equals(actual, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: Depending on where you read the string from, you may have some non-visible characters in there that create a difference.  Loop through each individual character in the string and display the integer code point for each one and look for a difference that way.  You may be surprised by what you find.

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint before "return expected.Equals(actual);", expected and actual have the same value?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Another thing to consider. I can type `a` in English and `а` in Russian. They are different characters although look exactly the same. Beware of these sort of issues.

Comment: Could you, please, provide both strings *encoded*, i.e.
`String.Join(" ", expected.Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4")));` and
`String.Join(" ", actual.Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4")));`

Comment: I checked the length for both string it is 9 only

Comment: I got the thing like i ptrinted its ascii value and  for actual space value is 160 and for expected space value is 32. But now how can i now move ahead??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got the thing like i ptrinted its ascii value and for actual space value is 160 and for expected space value is 32. But now how can i now move ahead??

One approach is to normalize your strings by replacing certain characters with a baseline.  In your case you can replace non-breaking spaces with a "normal" space:

```
 public bool VerifyTextPresent(By by, String actual)
{
        WaitUntilElementIsPresent(by);
        String expected = GetText(by);

        if (expected.Equals(actual)) return true;
        if (expected.Equals(Normalize(actual))) return true;
        return false;
}

private string Normalize(string s)
{
    // hard-code for now; could use a lookup table or other means to expand  
    s = s.Replace((char)160, (char)32);
    // other replacements as necessary

    return s;

}
```